# ++ Syntax for Content Inside Array?

Tags: java, increment, unary-operator

can you do `array[i]++`?

Is it the same as `array[i] = array[i] + 1`?

If not, why not? Is it something to do with how primitives vs references are treated?

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight difference: **postfix** vs **prefix** increment operator

1. If you use `array[i]++`, the old value will be used for the calculation and the value of `i` will be increased by 1 afterwards.
2. For `array[i] = array[i] + 1`, it's the opposite: `i` will first be incremented and only then the calculation will take place.

For more details, check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) out.

Comment: are you saying array[i]++ wouldn't actually reflect a change of +1 in the array since the old value is stored, not the new one?

Comment: Both will reflect a change of +1. The only difference is `order of operations` between the `increment of the variable` and the `value the operator returns`.

Comment: `array[i]++` only increments `array[i]` after the whole instruction it appears in is evaluated. So suppose in a loop, if you have `array[i] = 1` and `array[i]++`, it will wait until current iteration done, before increment the value of array[i] by `1`. So when you print it, it will still give `1`, but when next iteration start, without even increment `array[i]` it again, it will give you `2`. On the other hand, if you have `array[i] = 1` and `array[i] = array[i] + 1`, it will directly increment it, and print `2`. Hope this clarifies it.